# Android ViewPager Scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

I have an extended ViewPager class and I am using `onPageScrolled` to capture offset.

```
protected void onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetPixels)
```

and using `onTouchEvent` to control view scrolling

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {        
    if (this.isPagingEnabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}
```

I need to capture offset change while disabling viewpager scroll as if it was scrolling to show custom scrolling effects using `onDraw`

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom Scroller where you can change it's scroll duration...

```
package com.finoit.fsop.widgets;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private ScrollerCustomDuration mScroller = null;

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
        postInitViewPager();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (this.enabled) {
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (this.enabled) {
                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    } 

    /**
     * Override the Scroller instance with our own class so we can change the duration
     */
    private void postInitViewPager() {

        try {

                Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
                Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
                scroller.setAccessible(true);
                Field interpolator = viewpager.getDeclaredField("sInterpolator");
                interpolator.setAccessible(true);

                mScroller = new ScrollerCustomDuration(getContext(), (Interpolator) interpolator.get(null));
                scroller.set(this, mScroller);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

    /**
     * Set the factor by which the duration will change
     */
    public void setScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
            mScroller.setScrollDurationFactor(scrollFactor);
    }


}


package com.finoit.fsop.widgets;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.widget.Scroller;

public class ScrollerCustomDuration extends Scroller {

    private double mScrollFactor = 1;

    public ScrollerCustomDuration(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollerCustomDuration(Context context, Interpolator interpolator) {
        super(context, interpolator);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public ScrollerCustomDuration(Context context, Interpolator interpolator, boolean flywheel) {
        super(context, interpolator, flywheel);
    }

    /**
     * Set the factor by which the duration will change
     */
    public void setScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
        mScrollFactor = scrollFactor;
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, (int) (duration * mScrollFactor));
    }

}
```

For scrolling effects

```
@Overwrite onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetPixels)
```